# Error while connecting mist on private net

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, ubuntu

I want to connect the mist private net on ubuntu 16.04
step that i am doing to connect mist on private net are below:

1. create privatenet folder into ~.ethereum folder(which is into my Home folder).
2. also create one folder into name chaindata and make gensis.jason file into privatenet folder also.
3. run command geth --datadir ~/.ethereum/privatenet init ./privether/privategenesis.json
4. run command geth --datadir=. /.ethereum/privatenet/ --networkid 1234
5. then run command on other terminal geth attach ipc:.ethereum/privatenet/geth.ipc.
6. then open mist but it given error(attached screen shot)
                                                                                please help to get out this issue as I am new to ethereum mist setup[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mist is trying to run geth and since it is already running and connected to port 30303, it is throwing that error. You have to start Mist with you private networki ipc

`mist --rpc /YOURPATH/.ethereum/privatenet/geth.ipc`